# ClojureScript: Get a Hashmap of js/window

Tags: clojurescript

In ClojureScript I'm trying to convert (not recursively, only the lowest level) of the global window object into a hashmap.

Usually, if js-objects are not constructed by Object, the following interop helps:

```
(defn jsx->clj [js-o]
  (reduce (fn [m v]
            (assoc m (keyword v) (aget js-o v)))
          {} (.keys js/Object js-o)))
```

However, if I apply this to js/window I'm getting errors:

```
#object[TypeError TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string]
[...]
```

Has anyone made experiences with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The mysterious error is not in your code but happens when the repl attempts to output the result.**

Evaluate `js/cljs` in the repl to replicate, as this is the culprit.`(def foo (doall (jsx->clj js/window)))` works without a hitch except now the error appears if you evaluate `(pr foo)` in the repl or just `foo` by itself.

Comment: true, thanks for this. whyever this appears. anyways.. But something else ralated to this: I finely decided not to do this at all. my intention was to access a property from window by destructing: (let [{:keys [innerWidth innerHeight]} (jsx->clj js/window)] ...) however this is a huge perfomance problem. is there maybe another pattern to archive this? (whithout using aget imperatively)

Comment: Property access through destructuring was considered in [CLJS-248](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-248)

Comment: Consider defining a macro for a construct like
`(let-props [{:keys [innerWidth innerHeight]} js/window] ....)`

Comment: macros, I've never done one. Do you maybe have a snippet to get started?

Comment: You're up for a treat with macros. Here's one binding a property from a javascript object:``(defmacro let-prop [[name obj] & body] `(let [~name (aget ~obj ~(str name))] ~@body))``  Use like this: `(let-prop [innerWidth js/window] (str innerWidth))` Note the [differences from macros in clojure](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure#macros) though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ClojureScript library, [dom-types](https://github.com/lambdaisland/dom-types), can be a good solution to this kind of problem. After including lambdaisland.dom-types into your ClojureScript, you can get print and pprint handlers for various built-in types. This way instead of printing `#object[HTMLElement]` you'll get `#js/Element [:div "hello"]`.

After using this library, we can see `(prn js/window)` shows different results.

Demo:
[image]